# Sql injection and how to validate it in php

Tags: php, sql-injection

Is the following code vulnerable to Sql injections and how to validate it ?

```
$query=("select * from table2 where username = '$username'and password='$password'");
$result=  mysqli_query($connect, $query);
       $row=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if  ($username==$row['username']&&$password==$row['password'])
    {
        header('location:header.php');//to go header
        }
else
{
    header('location:insert_p.php');}
```

Comment: Depends what $username and $password look like. But unless you're filtering them before passing them in, yes, definitely.

Comment: Worth reading: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: Please don't store passwords in plaintext.

Comment: He didn't actually show us what's going on with either variable. He could be storing them in smiley notation for all we know.

Comment: Still a bad idea to write a query this way though. I would use pdo and bound variables after filtering the heck out of them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code seems vulnerable to SQL injections. Look at this line:

```
$query=("select * from table2 where username = '$username' and password='$password'");
```

Here you are passing the variables `$username` and `$password` directly to the database. If `$username` contains a string like `admin'; --` then there will be no check for the password.

## How to validate?

Just make sure, that every variable you directly put into an SQL statement is safe.

## Other solutions?

- You can use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` ([docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)) to escape special characters like `'`.
- You can use prepared statements. They seperate code and values. [This is a good start.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I wrote admin'; -- in username and the wrong password but still execute else